# Component not re-rendering when dictionary value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mobx, mobx-react

Simple: I change a dictionary value and the component is not re-rendering. The value actually changes when I log it, it just doesn't render on the screen.

This is where it's happening. The Icon should change from 'caret-down' to 'caret-right' but for some reason it's not:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {inject,observer} from 'mobx-react';


@inject("appStore") @observer
class Attribute extends Component {
    ...

    toggleValueDisplay = (attr) => {
        node.attributeToggle[attr] = !node.attributeToggle[attr];
    };

    render() {
        ...
        const { node, attr } = this.props;
        let vals = node.attributes.get(attr);

        return (
            <div>
                <span>
                    <div>{attr}</div>
                    <Icon type={node.attributeToggle[attr] ? "caret-down" : "caret-right"} onClick={(attr) => {this.toggleValueDisplay(attr)}}/>
                </span>
                    ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Attribute;
```

This is where the Attribute component is being rendered:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {inject,observer} from 'mobx-react';
import Attribute from "./attribute";

@inject("appStore") @observer
class Tab extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
        let node = this.props.appStore.repo.canvas.currentNode;

        return (
            <div className="tab-body">
            {/* ATTRIBUTES */}
            {
                <div>
                    <h5>Attributes</h5>
                    {
                        [...node.attributes.keys()].map((attr) => {
                            return <Attribute node={node} attr={attr} key={attr}/>
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Tab;
```

This is the Node object, for reference

```
import {observable} from 'mobx';

export default class Node {

    id = '';
    ...
    @observable attributes = new Map(); // {attribute : [values]}
    @observable attributeToggle = {}; // {attribute : bool}

    constructor(r) {
        for (let property in r) {
            this.attributes.set(property, r[property]);
            this.attributeToggle[property] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

========================= THINGS I HAVE TRIED =========================

I've tried changing this:

```
{
    node.attributeToggle[attr] ?
        <Icon type="caret-down" onClick={(attr) => {this.toggleValueDisplay(attr)}}/>
    :
        <Icon type="caret-down" onClick={(attr) => {this.toggleValueDisplay(attr)}}/>
}
```

and also this where the Attribute component is used in Tab

```
{/* ATTRIBUTES */}
{
    <div>
        <h5 >Attributes</h5>
        {
            [...node.attributes.keys()].map((attr) => { 
                return <Attribute node={this.props.appStore.repo.canvas.currentNode} attr={attr} key={attr}/>
            })
        }
    </div>
}
```

but it doesn't work. Not sure why this isn't working please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using props which are not mutable use state instead

Comment: But shouldn't mobx take care of that - I've marked everything as observable and the components are observers

Answer (score -2):

You don't trigger the component render anywhere, so of course it doesn't update. You can do it manually like this:

```
toggleValueDisplay = (attr) => {
        node.attributeToggle[attr] = !node.attributeToggle[attr];
        this.forceUpdate()
    };
```

Comment: Shouldn't the observable / observer tags in mobx trigger the re-render in this case?